# Can I pull reports from Rally (using the Rally Rest Api and Java)

Tags: java, rest, report, rally

I am new to the Rally Rest Api and was wondering if it's possible to pull reports from Rally (I'm using Java) so that we can display them on our custom app. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Rally analytics API, Lookback, to query our historical data to build reports across Stories and Defects.  The full docs can be round here:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual

Unfortunately, there isn't a canned Java toolkit for this API at this time, but you can use any standard http client library such as [Apache's HttpClient library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), as the API supports   GET and POST requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the Rally API here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/. This will give you an indication of the types of data available via API calls.

There is also a Java tool kit available here to help you bootstrap your work: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava.